# How to change +layout.svelte component on page navigation in svelte?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am new to svelte so I cannot figure this out how to solve this after many tries. Imagine I have a component `Navbar.svelte` in the `$lib/component`. As usual I will add this component to my `+layout.svelte` file. What I am trying to do is make this Navbar dynamic so that the content of the Navbar changes according to my page.

The idea comes from **Dynamic Island (Apple iPhone) and I want a navbar that is always stays on top and responsive like that**.

(This is one of the reasons why I put my `<Navbar/>` in +layout.svelte because I will be using page transitions and I don't want the navbar to be a part of the page transition, it will stay on top always visible) Here is an example taken from my project.

File: Navbar.svelte

```
<nav> 
    <slot> 
        <a href="/another-page"> Another Page </a> 
        <h1> This is navbar for home </h1> 
    </slot> 
</nav
```

File: +layout.svelte

```
<script> // imports </script> 
<Navbar/> 
<slot/> 
<Footer/>
```

File: +page.svelte

```
<h1> This is a Home page </h1>
```

How can I change the navbar when I click on the `/another-page` link so that in /another-page my navbar will contain only these:

```
<a href="/"> Home </a> 
<h1> This is navbar for Another Page </h1>
```

I tried named slots but it seems like +layout.svelte only accepts one slot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a Svelte store to pass around the constructor of the navbar component you want.  You can see a live demo [here](https://www.sveltelab.dev/1r9x33a5ohibmnz).

### Explanation

We use `<svelte:component>` in the `routes/+layout.svelte` file and bind that component to a simple writable store named `currentNavBar`.

We then create 2 navbar components:  `HomeNavBar` and `AnotherPageNavBar`.

Then, in `routes/+page.svelte`, we set the store value to be the constructor of `HomeNavBar`.  We also do the equivalent needful in `routes/anotherpage/+page.svelte`.

This is `routes/+layout.svelte`:

```html
<script>
    import './global.css';
    import currentNavBar from '../stores/currentNavBar.js';
</script>

<svelte:component this={$currentNavBar} />

<slot />
```

This is `stores/currentNavBar.js`:

```html
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export default writable(undefined);
```

This is `routes/+page.svelte`, the homepage, the script part:

```html
<script>
    import HomeNavBar from '$lib/NavBars/HomeNavBar.svelte';
    import currentNavbar from '../stores/currentNavBar.js';

    export let data;

    $currentNavbar = HomeNavBar;
</script>
```

This is `routes/anotherpage/+page.svelte`:

```html
<script>
    import AnotherPageNavBar from '$lib/NavBars/AnotherPageNavBar.svelte';
    import currentNavBar from '../../stores/currentNavBar.js';

    $currentNavBar = AnotherPageNavBar;
</script>

<h1>This is Another Page</h1>
```